# How to execute command under if statement in Shell Script under expect condition?

Tags: shell-script, shell, expect

```
send "if [ `ps -ef | grep ttyS1 | sed -n 1p | cut -d ' ' -f 2` -eq 'ttyS1' ]; then
not_found='false'
else 
not_found='true'
fi\r"
```

I have tried so many time with double quote and single quote also under ttyS1 but it is showing 
 1) ttyS1: unknown operand
 2) Bad Number for double quote

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `-eq` which is for comparing numbers. Your `=` when you compare strings

```
send "if [ `ps -ef | grep ttyS1 | sed -n 1p | cut -d ' ' -f 2` = 'ttyS1' ]; then
not_found='false'
else 
not_found='true'
fi\r"
```

And you can use double quotes as they are used already. You can also leave string `ttyS1` w/o any quotes